# Remove Windows 10 password (after trying the guides)

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I follow the guides to remove the password.

It worked for half of year but recently it started to ask me for the password again. (I checked the guide again - it didn't change)

The first screen that appears after restart claims that there is an issue with the network, I press OK and then I need to enter the password.

I'm using WiFi, but there is no issue with my network.

How can I remove it?

Comment: If it worked for half a year and then stopped, something has changed on your system.  Try following the guide again.  If the problem repeats, you would need to provide a lot more system and diagnostic information for people here to be able to help.  That's not a common error, so just the symptom won't be enough to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @fixer1234 tried it couple of times - didn't help...what kind of info do you want me to provide?

Comment: Given what you've tried, this would be hard to solve within the constraints of the site's Q&A format.  Unfortunately, the site isn't set up to facilitate troubleshooting problems, so we're  just not a good resource for this.  An interactive forum like https://windowsforum.com or https://www.tenforums.com might be a more effective venue for this kind of problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks! - I edited the question. is it clearer?

Comment: It’s asking for your password because the initial login failed, that would happen, regardless if you had a password or not.  However, a local account linked to a Microsoft Account must have a password, but you can automatically login to that account.  Your issue appears to be a networking issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that Microsoft has this bug that if you changed the password of your Microsoft account after disabling the pass request - it's not asking for re-entering the password or even give a hint about the fact that the password has changed - it just says that there is a network issue.

So in case someone will face this issue in the future - so the solution is just repeating the steps.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Being forced to reenter passwords is not normal behavior.

First aid :

- Repeat the action described in your guide
- Deep scan your computer with more than one anti-virus. I recommend
  that one should be [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

Comment: Thanks!
tried your steps..didn't help...:(

Comment: See if this is happening when booting in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in into your user profile using Microsoft account requires you to enter the password to access the Windows.

If you do not want to use password to login into Windows, create another Local account user, and use the account without entering the password.
Follow the steps below to create a Local user account:

1. Type Settings in the search box next to Start button, and select the top most search result.
2. Select Accounts from the options shown in the window.
3. Click on Family & other users from the left side panel, and click on Add someone else to this PC option under Other Users.
4. Click on I don’t have this person’s sign-in information located at the bottom of the window.
5. Click on Add a user without a Microsoft Account located at the bottom of the window, and follow the on-screen instructions.

If you're using a local account with a password, you can delete the password to sign in without one, but we don't recommend it.

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
   (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Search.)
2. Enter sign, and then tap or click Sign-in options.
3. Under Password, tap or click Change.
4. Verify the current password for your local account.
5. Leave the New password, Reenter password, and Password hint fields blank, tap or click Next, and then tap or click Finish.

Now, you (or anyone) can sign in to your local account and use your PC without a password.

Refer to the below link on Can I sign in to Windows without password? (Applies to Windows 10 also)

[Can I sign in to Windows without a password?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/14064/windows-8-sign-in-to-windows-without-password)

Comment: You can automatically log into a local account linked to a Microsoft account.